# Expressionengine does not allow php script to execute

Tags: php, expressionengine

In ExpressionEngine Admin area,
I have set option in

> TemmplateManager -> Template -> Preferences -> Allow PHP set to Yes.

And it is still not executing the PHP script for that page (where PHP is applied on this template).

Not sure what is wrong, can anybody help me with this?

I have attached screenshots below.

[EE admin screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBqLr.png)

[Render PHP on HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDB13.png)

Comment: Have you tried turing on template debugging?

Comment: Have you tried changing "PHP Parsing Stage" to input? It may be your page is rendering all the EE stuff first and not going back and doing the PHP wrapped around it. Having parsing set to input will execute all your PHP code before the EE code which from your small sample seems to be what you want to do.

Comment: Did someone get this solved? I'm facing the same issue here

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow each template to allow PHP and set it to input so that the PHP renders BEFORE the template.